# Need help with Zend form Validation

Tags: zend-framework, forms

Currently Im developing on a website with Zend framework.

I needed to develop a location field similar to the one found here: http://www.truelocal.com.au/

Which allow user to input PostCode Values (consist of 4 numbers) or Suburb Name

I'm stuck at the moment in the Zend form validation part

Basically I need to ensure the Postcode values or Suburb Name exist in the database.

I'm able to use `Zend_Validate_Db_RecordExists` easily to check if the Postcode exist in my database.

```
$validator = new Zend_Validate_Db_RecordExists('postcodeTable', 'postcode');
```

But how can I also add another Suburb name Validation to check if Suburb Name exist in the database (Without conflicting with the Postcode validation check)?

Is there a clear and easy way to achieve this?

Do I need to write a custom validator? If so how can I do it?

Thanks so much in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can alias validators, like you can decorators, but you could extend Zend_Validate_Db_RecordExists, for example:

```
class App_Validate_Db_SuburbExists
    extends Zend_Validate_Db_RecordExists
{

}
```

Don't forget to add your library's validator prefixPath to the element e.g.

```
$element->addPrefixPath('App_Validate_Db', 'App/Validate/Db', 'validate');
```

Then you can add both validators with different options.

```
$element->addValidator(
            new App_Validate_Db_SuburbExists('suburbTable', 'suburb'))

        ->addValidator(
            new Zend_Validate_Db_RecordExists('postcodeTable', 'postcode'));
```

Comment: If you are adding a concrete instantiation of a validator you probably won't need to set the prefix path. but if you want to lazy load the validators then you will have to provide the path.

Answer (score 0):

I think of custom validator which is just a proxy

something like this

```
$proxyValidator = new App_Validate_Proxy(); //implements Zend_Validate_Interface
$proxyValidator->addValidator($validateDb1);
$proxyValidator->addValidator($validateDb2);
```

at least one of subvalidators must return true to consider value as valid

$proxyValidator::isValid():

```
public function isValid($value)
{
    foreach($this->_validators as $validator) {
        $validator->isValid($value) ? return true : $this->_messages[] = $validator->getMessages();
    }
    return false;
}
```